# 'typo of' or 'typo for' or no preposition applicable?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

If I see *inkorrect* instead of *incorrect* in a paragraph, how should I report it using the word *typo*?

Should I say

- *inkorrect* is a typo *of* *incorrect*.
- *inkorrect* is a typo *for* *incorrect*.
- or something else?

I have checked in [Oxford](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/typo?q=typo), [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/typo), [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/typo), and 
[Websters](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/typo), but found no usage with preposition.

Comment: Unless there are many such instances, or for usage in formal writing, I would write out "typographical error".

Answer (score 4):

You would use [for](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/for), meaning "in place of":

> 1. in place of; instead of"   ⇒ *to use blankets for coats*"

so:

> inkorrect is a typo **for** incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

**Both "of" and "for" can be used.**. As user3169 posted, "for" can be used to denote the typo is "in place of" the correct spelling. However, ["of"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/of) is equally valid:

> 1. from:
>
>    a. derived or coming from

and

> 3. belonging to

"Of" establishes that "inkorrect" is derived from and associated with "incorrect". "For" suggests that the typo is actively being used to replacing the correct spelling.

Preference between them may be regional. I'm on the East coast of the U.S., while user3169 is on the West coast.